# Пунктуация в "влияние антагониста рецепторов ангиотензина II лозартана на состояние почек"

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

> Влияние антагониста рецепторов ангиотензина II лозартана на состояние почек и сердечно-сосудистой системы у больных сахарным диабетом типа 2 с нефропатией.

Лозартан – это лекарственное средство (неторговое, непатентованное название). Антагонисты рецепторов ангиотензина II – группа лекарственных средств, к которой относится лозартан, названы так по механизму их действия.

Почему "лозартана" не выделяется никакими знаками? Почему нельзя поставить запятые или одно тире (по Розенталю: приложение выражает конкретное значение, предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение)?

Еще у Розенталя есть такое правило:

> Дефис не пишется: если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое: цветок хризантема, дерево эвкалипт, гриб подосиновик, птица зяблик.

Применимо ли здесь оно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова «род» и «вид» тут в понимании как в логике:

> *Лог.* Понятие, включающее в себя ряд менее общих понятий,
> представляющих собой видовые понятия. [Словарь русского языка  Евгеньевой]

Род по иерархии находится выше вида. Все виды чего-то входят в род.

Например:
Цветок — род, в него входят виды *цветов*: роза, хризантема, тюльпан и т. п.

Тут ситуация аналогичная:
Антагонист рецепторов ангиотензина II — род, в него входят виды *антагониста рецепторов ангиотензина II*: ангиаканд, лозартан, канарб, валсартан и т. п. [по данным [vidal.ru](https://www.vidal.ru/drugs/clinic-group/22)]

Поэтому, как вы правильно указали, тире не ставится:

> 2. если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое
>    обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое: цветок хризантема,
>    дерево эвкалипт, гриб подосиновик, птица зяблик, попугай какаду,
>    обезьяна макака, краска серебрянка, газ углерод, нитки мулине, ткань
>    нейлон, леденцы монпансье, суп харчо. [[old-rozental.ru](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)]

Если поставить запятую, это может быть принято за однородные члены предложения, как будто идёт перечисление.

Если вы хотите отделить для наглядности, я бы сделал так:

*Влияние лозартана (антагониста рецепторов ангиотензина II)  на состояние почек и сердечно-сосудистой системы у больных сахарным диабетом типа 2 с нефропатией.*

---

Названия лекарств, взятые для примера, выбраны без значка торговой марки и написаны с маленькой буквы. Не разбираюсь в лекарствах, поэтому не знаю, что пишут с большой, а что с маленькой.

Согласно [gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

> **Названия лекарств и медицинских препаратов оформляются на письме так:**
> при употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия лекарственных
> средств следует писать с прописной буквы в кавычках: «Агри»,
> «Инфлювак», «Афлубин», «Фервекс»,  а в бытовом употреблении – со
> строчной буквы без кавычек, например: выпить фервекс, принять виагру.
> Также пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек некоторые названия
> лекарств, вошедшие в широкий обиход вследствие многолетнего
> употребления (валидол, анальгин, аспирин).

Но даже если считать название лекарства именем собственным и писать с большой буквы, то всё равно:

> Дефис пишется после имени собственного (чаще всего — географического
> названия, **выступающего в роли приложения при родовом наименовании**):
> Москва-река, Ильмень-озеро, Казбек-гора, Астрахань-город (**но при
> обратном порядке слов: река Москва, озеро Ильмень, гора Казбек, город
> Астрахань**; выражения типа матушка-Русь, матушка-земля имеют характер
> устойчивых сочетаний). [[old-rozental.ru](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)]

Например:

> Препарат для симптоматической терапии острых респираторных заболеваний
> «Фервекс». [Клинико-фармакологическая группа по данным [vidal.ru]](https://www.vidal.ru/drugs/fervex__21640)

Comment: Слово "лозартан" может обозначать как действующее вещество, так и название препарата. Думаю, что в цитате из вопроса речь идёт о действующем веществе (лозартане калия).

Comment: @grizzly В вопросе есть пояснение: «Лозартан — это лекарственное средство».

Comment: Да, названия действующих веществ (международные непатентованные названия) пишут с маленькой буквы, названия препаратов пишут с большой буквы. Вот тут первые абзацы можете почитать, если интересно: https://www.brkmed.ru/article/o-nazvaniyah-lekarstvennyh-sredstv/

Comment: @athlonusm А что насчёт сути ответа? Вы его не оценили. Вам подходит? Есть какие-то замечания?

Comment: @athlonusm Спасибо за оценку!